Clerk gives auth error when using Next.js route handlers
INFO: Clerk: The request to /api/send is being protected (401) because there is no signed-in user, and the path is included in `apiRoutes`. To prevent this behavior, choose one of:

Getting the above error while using the /api/send route in my next.js app.
The following is the middleware.js file
import { authMiddleware } from '@clerk/nextjs';

export default authMiddleware({
  // Routes that can be accessed while signed out
  publicRoutes: ['/', '/featured', '/products'],
  // Routes that can always be accessed, and have
  // no authentication information
  ignoredRoutes: ['/', '/how-it-works', '/studio'],
  apiRoutes: ['/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
});

export const config = {
  // Protects all routes, including api/trpc.
  // See https://clerk.com/docs/references/nextjs/auth-middleware
  // for more information about configuring your Middleware
  matcher: ['/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
};

Note:

it works if I add /(api|trpc)(.*) in ignoredRoutes or publicRoutes. But I want my api routes to be protected.
middleware.js file is inside src folder.

Tried going through the docs but could not find any possible answer for this error
